# How to update specific ini key in specific section?

Tags: c#, ini

I'm using this library: https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser/wiki/First-Steps
I can't figure out how can I update a specific key in a specific section. In particular:

```
[UI]
fullscreen = false
```

how can I change `fullscreen = true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
IniData data = parser.ReadFile("YourConfiguration.ini");
data["UI"]["fullscreen"] = true.ToString().ToLower();
parser.WriteFile("YourConfiguration.ini", data);
```

Comment: hey, project maintainer here. You don't actually need the `.ToLower()` However being able to directly assign a primitive type to an key in the ini seems like a good idea, so I'll add it to the library. Thanks!

Comment: @RicardoAmores I added the `.ToLower()` since `true.ToString().ToLower()` return `True` but in the OP's example it was `true`. Adding direct support for this feature would be great!

Comment: Nice catch, I said that because ’bool.Parse()’ works correctly with the string 'True' but maybe this INI file is consumed by others that require the specific 'true' string. About adding that feature: Easier said than done :( I've just tried and didn't realize that I can't overload the index operator with multiple values, and changing it to accept objects breaks compatibility. I'm not giving up, maybe I can create a proxy object with implicit conversion to a string